# Share data between iOS simulators

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

For example iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus have different simulators (WHY, Apple?). I need make same screenshots for different iPhone simulator versions for App Store. My app is showing some data, which i keep with NSUserDefaults. I can use NSCoding protocol, if it will help.

So, what is best and easy way to share my data?

Any comment for voting down? I have difficult data and i can't just imput her manually.

Comment: Perhaps you can alter your code to save the data to your desktop as opposed to your device when it's being run in the simulator.

Comment: I thought about save data into NSData using NSCoding, but i don't know how grab this data from a simulator after saving. I'm have about 1.8E20 random states. I'll try find a way, thanks. @LyndseyScott

Comment: It's a shame they changed this. Now creating screenshots for 5 screen sizes has become a chore.